# Does the number of estimators in an ensemble have any effect on model complexity?

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning

First off, what I understand by "model complexity" is, roughly, the dimensionality of the parameter space. More complex means more variance (less bias) and therefore more tendency to overfit.

Intuitivelly, I'd expect an ensemble to have more learning parameters than a single estimator (the more estimators composing the ensemble, the more parameters, I'd imagine).
However, my intuition also says that bigger ensembles are better at preventing overfitting (which would mean they add a bias to the model, i.e. decrease model complexity).

Is my understanding of model complexity correct? And which part of my intuition is betraying me?